# Valid lists inside lists - ul inside ul

Tags: html, w3c, html-lists

I need lists inside lists.

What's the most valid way?

```
<ul>
  <li>
      <ul>
          <li><h2>title</h2></li>
          <li>element</li>
          <li>element</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
      <ul>
          <li><h2>title</h2></li>
          <li>element</li>
          <li>element</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
```

Would that be valid? And semantic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**VALID**, except your second `<h2>` needs to be in a `<li>`.  You can nest them as much as you want.